# Install Ingres extension for PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ingres

PHP Ingres failing with message:

```
/usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size
```

I have a working Ingres installation.

Building and linking does not complain but when trying to run or to make test the above error is raised.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Tried with Ingres:

```
ingres-10.0.0-132-NPTL-com-pc-linux-ingbuild-i386
and ingres-9.2.1-103-NPTL-com-pc-linux-ingbuild-i386

env...

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib
    PATH=/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/bin:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/utility:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
    II_SYSTEM=/opt/Ingres/IngresII

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"




$ phpize

    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20090626
    Zend Module Api No:      20090626
    Zend Extension Api No:   220090626

$ ./configure

    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for cc... cc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
    checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
    checking for icc... no
    checking for suncc... no
    checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking for system library directory... lib
    checking if compiler supports -R... no
    checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
    checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for PHP prefix... /usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
    checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
    checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
    checking if debug is enabled... no
    checking if zts is enabled... no
    checking for re2c... re2c
    checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for nawk... nawk
    checking if nawk is broken... no
    checking for improved Ingres support... yes, shared
    checking Use ingres2 as the extension name... no
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
    checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for mt... mt
    checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: executing libtool commands



    $ make
     /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/ingres  /ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c -o ingres.lo
    libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ingres.o
    /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c: In function 'php_ii_gen_cursor_id':
    /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c:2980:5: warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/convertUTF.c -o convertUTF.lo
    libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/convertUTF.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/convertUTF.o
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o ingres.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules  ingres.lo convertUTF.lo -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lcompat.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lframe.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lq.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -liiapi.1
    libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/ingres.o .libs/convertUTF.o   -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lcompat.1 -lframe.1 -lq.1 -liiapi.1  -O2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib   -Wl,-soname -Wl,ingres.so -o .libs/ingres.so
    libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "ingres.la" && ln -s "../ingres.la" "ingres.la" )
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=install cp ./ingres.la /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules
    libtool: install: cp ./.libs/ingres.so /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules/ingres.so
    libtool: install: cp ./.libs/ingres.lai /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules/ingres.la
    libtool: finish: PATH="/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/bin:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/utility:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/bin:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/utility:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin" ldconfig -n /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Libraries have been installed in:
       /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Build complete.
    Don't forget to run 'make test'.







    $ make test

    Build complete.
    Don't forget to run 'make test'.

    /usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size
    /usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size

    =====================================================================
    PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
    CWD         : /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3
    Extra dirs  :
    VALGRIND    : Not used
    =====================================================================
    TIME START 2012-06-14 10:19:01
    =====================================================================
    FAIL Ingres: Bug #15586 - test for white space handling at the start of a query [tests/bug_15586.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug #15586 - test for a new line at the start of a query [tests/bug_15586_newlines.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug 16752 - Passing zero length strings based on PHP types [tests/bug_16752_1.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug 16752 - Passing zero length strings using parameter typing [tests/bug_16752_2.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug 16752 - Passing zero length strings based on DESCRIBE INPUT [tests/bug_16752_3.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug 16990 - SEGV when executing a procedure [tests/bug_16990_procedure_segv.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug #17302 - Test for closure of statements [tests/bug_17302.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Bug #17556 - test for error handling in non-result returning statements [tests/bug_17556.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Insert a boolean value using DESCRIBE INPUT. [tests/insert_boolean_1.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: Insert a boolean value using a static query. [tests/insert_boolean_2.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: connect to a database as current user [tests/test_001.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: connect to a database with user+password [tests/test_002.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: execute a simple select against default link - no results returned. [tests/test_003.phpt]
    FAIL Ingres: execute a simple select against default link - fetch object. [tests/test_
     /usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size


    Anything obvious that I am missing?

    here are the output from my installation.

    Your assistants is much appreciated.


    Tried with ingres:
    ingres-10.0.0-132-NPTL-com-pc-linux-ingbuild-i386
    and ingres-9.2.1-103-NPTL-com-pc-linux-ingbuild-i386




    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"




    $ phpize
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20090626
    Zend Module Api No:      20090626
    Zend Extension Api No:   220090626


    $ ./configure
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for cc... cc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
    checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
    checking for icc... no
    checking for suncc... no
    checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking for system library directory... lib
    checking if compiler supports -R... no
    checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
    checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for PHP prefix... /usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
    checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
    checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
    checking if debug is enabled... no
    checking if zts is enabled... no
    checking for re2c... re2c
    checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for nawk... nawk
    checking if nawk is broken... no
    checking for improved Ingres support... yes, shared
    checking Use ingres2 as the extension name... no
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
    checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for mt... mt
    checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: executing libtool commands

$ make

    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c -o ingres.lo
    libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ingres.o
    /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c: In function 'php_ii_gen_cursor_id':
    /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/ingres.c:2980:5: warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/convertUTF.c -o convertUTF.lo
    libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/convertUTF.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/convertUTF.o
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/include -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/main -I/home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o ingres.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules  ingres.lo convertUTF.lo -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lcompat.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lframe.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lq.1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -liiapi.1
    libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/ingres.o .libs/convertUTF.o   -L/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -lcompat.1 -lframe.1 -lq.1 -liiapi.1  -O2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib   -Wl,-soname -Wl,ingres.so -o .libs/ingres.so
    libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "ingres.la" && ln -s "../ingres.la" "ingres.la" )
    /bin/sh /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/libtool --mode=install cp ./ingres.la /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules
    libtool: install: cp ./.libs/ingres.so /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules/ingres.so
    libtool: install: cp ./.libs/ingres.lai /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules/ingres.la
    libtool: finish: PATH="/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/bin:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/utility:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/bin:/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/utility:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin" ldconfig -n /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Libraries have been installed in:
       /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3/modules

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Build complete.
    Don't forget to run 'make test'.







$ make test

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

/usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size
/usr/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so: undefined symbol: adg_srv_size

=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
CWD         : /home/ingres/ingres-2.2.3
Extra dirs  :
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================
TIME START 2012-06-14 10:19:01
=====================================================================



    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has now been fixed in the latest release 2.2.4 - you can download the code via http://pecl.php.net/get/ingres. The order of the libraries used to link with Ingres seems to have changed or has become more sensitive.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, libiiapi is dependent on libq, on my HP-UX boxes ldd displays a dependency but not on linux.  

`nm $II_SYSTEM/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so | grep adg_srv_size  U adg_srv_size  ldd $II_SYSTEM/ingres/lib/libiiapi.1.so 
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77ad000)
 libcompat.1.so => /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libcompat.1.so (0xb75fa000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb75f1000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb75c4000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb741f000)
`

Comment: `libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7404000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb73ff000)
 libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb73ce000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77ae000)
`

Comment: found a workaround:  `export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/lib/libq.1.so`  Still looking for permanent solution.

Comment: try swapping lines 35/36 in config.m4. You'll have to do `phpize && ./configure .....`

Comment: No Luck, same problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For some reason the linker is not including libq.1.so, it's there in the makefile but not there in the list of linked libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `./configure --with-ingres=/opt/Ingres/IngresII`

Comment: Resulting in the same problem,   see comment to Grantc